# Самая простая система плагинов

Tags: php, плагин

```
Здравствуйте.
```

можно-ли считать этот код принципом понимая системы плагинов ?
если нет объясните в чём я не прав.
код ну очень простой.

```
class plugin {

private $plugins=array();

function setPlug($hook,$func_name){
    $this->plugins[$hook]=$func_name;
}

private function call(){
    foreach($this->plugins as $func_name){
        if(function_exists($func_name)){
            call_user_func($func_name);
        }
    }
}

function delete_hook($name){
    if(array_key_exists($name,$this->plugins)){
        unset($this->plugins[$name]);
    }
}

function __destruct(){
    $this->call();
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основная проблема здесь в том, что у вас плагин - это какая-то внешняя функция или метод какого-то класса, это не совсем правильно, т.к плагином может быть целый класс и набор классов.

В данном случае если использовать класс или набор классов, то придется для вашего метода setPlug постоянно писать что-то типа метода-фабрики для создания объекта плагина и вызова его какого-то основного метода, а это не тру.

Можно вот что сделать, написать какой-то универсальный интерфейс/абстрактный класс для всех плагинов, указать в нем парочку обязательных методов, например для инициализации и для запуска. В вашем классе плагин методе setPlug жестко задать тип:

```
function setPlug($hook, plugin_interface $func_name){/* ... */}
```

И спокойной внутри этого класса дергать методы плагина, которые заставляет реализовывать `plugin_interface`, не боясь, что их может не быть, без всяких `function_exists` и т.п

```
<?php
interface plugin_interface
{
    public function call();
}

class plugin_storage
{
    protected $plugins = array();

    public function add_plugin(plugin_interface $plugin) {
        $this->plugins[] = $plugin;
        return $this;
    }

    public function call_plugins() {
        foreach ($this->plugins as $plugin) {
            /** @var plugin_interface $plugin_instance */
            $plugin_instance = new $plugin;
            $plugin_instance->call();
        }
        return $this;
    }
}

class plugin_foo implements plugin_interface
{
    public function call() {
        echo 'foo<br/>';
    }
}

class plugin_bar implements plugin_interface
{
    public function call() {
        echo 'bar<br/>';
    }
}

$plugin_storage = new plugin_storage;
$plugin_storage->add_plugin(new plugin_foo())
               ->add_plugin(new plugin_bar())
               ->call_plugins();
```

Comment: вод бы примерчик, такой реализации

Comment: добавил, но сильно упрощенно

Comment: Спасибо огромное !