# Добавление операций в калькулятор в виде плагинов

Tags: java, swing, плагин

Есть простейший калькулятор, написанный на Swing, который реализует простые операции - сложение, вычитание, умножение, деление. Необходимо реализовать механизм добавления операций в виде плагинов непосредственно во время выполнения программы. Каким образом такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте это:

https://www.osgi.org/developer/specifications/.

Здесь приведён пример простейшей реализации:

[Самая простая система плагинов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/326096/%d0%a1%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2?rq=1)